# The given key '22' is not found in the dictionary

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

This error showed up when I tried to login on my application...
My suspicion is that SqlDbType.VarChar ( it has an integer of 22 ) is not detected by Visual Basic or MySql Connector is bugged... But, what do you think of this?

[The VarChar ID is not detected...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEDav.png)

Here's the code to pressing the login button:

```
Private Sub loginMenu_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles loginMenu.Click
    Dim val As Integer

    If userTextBoxMenu.Text = "" Or passTextBoxMenu.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in username and password, please.")
    Else
        Try
            sqlConn.Open()
            sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            'sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM admin_account WHERE username = '" & userTextBoxMenu.Text & "' AND password = '" & passTextBoxMenu.Text & "'"
            sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM admin_account WHERE username = @userN AND password = @passW;"
            sqlAdap = New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlComm.CommandText, sqlConn)

            sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@userN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
            sqlComm.Parameters("@userN").Value = userTextBoxMenu.Text
            sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@passW", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = passTextBoxMenu.Text
            sqlComm.Parameters("@passW").Value = passTextBoxMenu.Text

            val = sqlAdap.Fill(dataTab)
            sqlConn.Close()

            If val = 1 Then
                statusLabelMenu.Text = "Logged In"
                sqlComm.Parameters.Clear()
            ElseIf val = 0 Then
                userTextBoxMenu.Text = ""
                passTextBoxMenu.Text = ""
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!")
                sqlComm.Parameters.Clear()
            ElseIf val > 1 Then
                userTextBoxMenu.Text = ""
                passTextBoxMenu.Text = ""
                MessageBox.Show("WARNING! SQL injection attack detected. Authorities noted.")
                sqlComm.Parameters.Clear()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please change `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)` to `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message & " " & ex.StackTrace)` so we can see where the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlDbType is for use with the SqlClient provider for SQL Server. Not surprisingly, the MySqlDbType enumeration is for use with the MySqlClient provider for MySQL.